# How to implement QT incremental installation?

Tags: qt

I didn't install MSVC when installing the software QT5.12. Now Qt5.12 has been installed. How can I easily install MSVC on the existing basis?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Do you mean you installed Qt framework version 5.12.X via the online installer (5.12.12 is the current) and now want to install some version of msvc but then want to go back and have the Qt installer install the Qt binaries for the new version of msvc?

Comment: I installed QT 5.12 offline. I didn't check the MSVC option during installation. In the subsequent use, I found that MSVC needs to be used. Now I want to install MSVC. Can I only uninstall QT and reinstall it?

Comment: I believe you can go back to the installer and install additional components.

Comment: I've tried this method you said, but after entering, the  page  of installer  doesn't show MSVC